# Jest in Turborepo with yarn workspaces: transformIgnorePatterns

Tags: jestjs, monorepo, babel-jest, turborepo

I'm trying to target a package called `oauth4webapi` in my `jest.config.ts` file in a local turborepo package. The package I'm tryng to target is in the root `node_modules` folder, not the local one. Is there a way to test if it's hitting the right path, as I'm struggling to make it work but the regex seems correct...

```js
// jest.config.ts
import path from 'path';

// ...
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    `${path.join(__dirname, "../..")}/node_modules/(?!(oauth4webapi))`
  ],
```

The [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring) has an example for pnpm in turborepo but not yarn workspaces which is unfortunate...